# Aligning div and section elements with flex CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm currently redoing some code to update to HTML5 (and trying to de-uglify CSS), but so far my alignment and layout doesn't seem to be working as expected. Here's part of what I have:

```
<main class="width">
    <div class="r1">
        <section class="c1">
            <h1>header</h1>
            stuff
        </section>
        <!--Line Break-->
        <section class="c1">
            <h1>header</h1>
            stuff
        </section>
    </div>
    <!--Next Column-->
    <div class="r2">
        <section class="c2">
            <h1>header</h1>
            stuff
        </section>
    </div>
</main>
```

CSS:

```
@font-face {
    font-family:'Roboto';
    font-style:normal;
    font-weight:400;
    src:url(/resources/font.woff) format('woff');
}
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-size:small;
    font-family:Roboto;
    vertical-align:middle;
    border:none;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.width {
    margin:0 auto;
    width:86%;
    min-width:1000px;
}
.bg {
    min-width:1000px;
    background:linear-gradient(#444, #000, #444);
}
main {
    line-height:1.5;
    text-align:center;
}
body>.main {
    font-size:0;
}
section {
    border:1px solid #BBB;
    background:#000;
    border-radius:7px;
    display:inline-block;
    overflow:hidden;
}
h1 {
    background:linear-gradient(#444, #000, #444);
    padding:5px;
    color:#FFF;
}
.r1 {
    color:#FFF;
    display:inline-block;
}
.r2 {
    color:#FFF;
    display:inline-block;
}
.c1 {
    width:33%;
}
.c2 {
    width:66%;
}
```

(Ignore r1 and c1 naming. They don't actually represent a row or column)

However, this does not work the way it used to. What I'm trying to do is to have two rows of 66% width columns above each other, and then next to them, a larger single 33% width column to the right of them. Instead, I've got the the first two sections on one line, taking up a total of 66% width (so each section is 33% width), and then the next section ends up underneath it.

Ideally, I want to use the flex code, so that I can use up all available space, but I'm still new to it, and don't know my way around it very well. The problem with using percentage widths is that even after white-space removal, things still break to the next line when zoomed in enough, and I think that the flex method is more elegant and modern anyway.

Comment: it inline => http://jsfiddle.net/MLsc8/ ...m i misunderstanding your question??

Comment: Was anything changed in the fiddle? Because if not, that's not what I'm seeing on my page locally.

Comment: i just copy pasted you code and added `border` to understand the width...that's it!! :)

Comment: I'm probably missing some CSS somewhere then. I'll look through my code again to see if I've missed something that should have been added to my question...

Comment: Alright, updated it: http://jsfiddle.net/MLsc8/3/ You can see that the top sections do not have the proper widths. I'm trying to get them like the bottom row, except that with the top row, there is one on top of the other on the left, and on the right, an element as tall as the other two combined. This is what is causing the issue, but I'd also like to try and see if I can flex box everything instead of using the widths to achieve 100% width of the container. Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: so basically u want all `div`s to have same width...right??

Comment: Okay, if I make a slight change to the fiddle and give each section a letter and some filler content: http://jsfiddle.net/N475x/ The two sections with 'headerA' should be as wide as the section with 'headerC'. The 'headerB' section for some reason is so tiny that you cant even read anything in it, but it should be as wide as the section with 'headerD'. every row of sections should be as wide as the middle section (the one just called 'header' that takes up an entire row on its own).